# How to query OrientDB asynchronously from Play controller?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.2, orientdb

I am writing a [Play](http://www.playframework.com) (2.2) controller in Scala, which should return the result of a query against [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/). Now, I have succeeded in writing a synchronous version of said controller, but I'd like to re-write it to work asynchronously.

My question is; given the below code (just put together for demonstration purposes), how do I re-write my controller to interact asynchronously with OrientDB (connecting and querying)?

```
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.libs.json._
import com.orientechnologies.orient.`object`.db.OObjectDatabasePool
import java.util
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Packages extends Controller {
  def packages() = Action { implicit request  =>
    val db = OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire("http://localhost:2480", "reader", "reader")
    try {
      db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(classOf[models.Package])
      val packages = db.query[util.List[models.Package]](new OSQLSynchQuery[models.Package]("select from Package")).asScala.toSeq
      Ok(Json.obj(
        "packages" -> Json.toJson(packages)
      ))
    }
    finally {
      db.close()
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Specifically, I wish to use OrientDB's asynchronous API. I know that asynchronous queries are supported by the API, though I'm not sure if you can connect asynchronously as well.

## Attempted Solution

Based on Jean's answer, I've tried the following asynchronous implementation, but it fails due to a compilation error `value execute is not a member of Nothing possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before 'value execute'?`:

```
def getPackages(): Future[Seq[models.Package]] = {
    val db = openDb
    try {
      val p = promise[Seq[models.Package]]
      val f = p.future
      db.command(
        new OSQLAsynchQuery[ODocument]("select from Package",
          new OCommandResultListener() {
            var acc = List[ODocument]()

            @Override
            def result(iRecord: Any): Boolean = {
              val doc = iRecord.asInstanceOf[ODocument]
              acc = doc :: acc
              true
            }

            @Override
            def end() {
              // This is just a dummy
              p.success(Seq[models.Package]())
            }
          // Fails
          })).execute()
      f
    }
    finally {
      db.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to start a promise, return the future representing the result of that promise, locally accumulate the results as they come and complete de promise ( thus resolving the future ) when orient db notifies you that the command has completed.

```
def executeAsync(osql: String, params: Map[String, String] = Map()): Future[List[ODocument]] = {
    import scala.concurrent._
    val p = promise[List[ODocument]]
    val f =p.future
    val req: OCommandRequest = database.command(
      new OSQLAsynchQuery[ODocument]("select * from animal where name = 'Gipsy'",
        new OCommandResultListener() {
          var acc = List[ODocument]()
          @Override
          def result(iRecord:Any):Boolean= {
            val doc = iRecord.asInstanceOf[ODocument]
            acc=doc::acc
            true
          }

          @Override
          def end() {
            p.success(acc)
          }
        }))
    req.execute()
    f
  }
```

Be careful though, to enable graph navigation and field lazy loading, orientdb objects used to keep an internal reference to the database instance they were loaded from ( or to depend on a threadlocal database connected instance ) for lazily loading elements from the database. Manipulating these objects asynchronously may result in loading errors. I haven't checked changes from 1.6 but that seemed to be deeply embedded in the design.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.

Comment: as mentionned this accumulates things locally, if you don't want to accumulate in the OCommandResultListener, you might be able to plug this on an enumerator or a scalaz-stream but I don't know the apis for these well enough to suggest code

Comment: Thanks Jean, will try to adapt this when I've got the time (soon hopefully).

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution, but it fails due to a compilation error. I've pasted the code at the bottom of my question. Any ideas as to what goes wrong?

Comment: I think I've fixed the compilation error by specifying the return type of database.command. However, now it fails due to an exception `IllegalStateException: Promise already completed.`.

Comment: I see that the end callback gets called twice, and the result callback never :(

Comment: I solved the previous problem, was probably due to some kind of bad state. So now, everything works except I need to return `models.Package` objects instead of `ODocument`. How do I convert?

Comment: I figured out I could convert ODocuments manually to models.Package objects, I guess there's no better way when dealing with ODocuments. Is there no way to have the async API return POJOs?

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as wrapping the blocking call in a Future.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Packages extends Controller {
  def packages = Action.async { implicit request  =>
    val db = OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire("http://localhost:2480", "reader", "reader")
    db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(classOf[models.Package])

    val futureResult: Future[Result] = Future(
      db.query[util.List[models.Package]](new OSQLSynchQuery[models.Package]("select from Package")).asScala.toSeq
    ).map(
      queryResult => Ok(Json.obj("packages" -> Json.toJson(packages)))
    ).recover { 
      // Handle each of the exception cases legitimately
      case e: UnsupportedOperationException => UnsupportedMediaType(e.getMessage)
      case e: MappingException              => BadRequest(e.getMessage)
      case e: MyServiceException            => ServiceUnavailable(e.toString)
      case e: Throwable                     => InternalServerError(e.toString + "\n" + e.getStackTraceString) 
    }

    futureResult.onComplete { case _ => 
      db.close()
    }

    futureResult
  }
}
```

Note that I did not compile the code. There is a lot of room to improve the code.

Comment: I wish to use OrientDB's async API, rather than blocking a thread waiting on a synchronous query.

Comment: I haven't used OrientDB.. but in the above approach you are not blocking a thread because Future object which contains the read handle to the data is immediately returned.. so its completely asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, the controller method returns immediately, but a thread must still block on the synchronous query, no? I'm new to Scala, but this is a well-known work-around for synchronous APIs. I know that OrientDB has an [asynchronous API](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Document-Database#wiki-asynchronous-query) however, so it isn't necessary.

Comment: I wrapped the blocking call in a Future. It's not blocking anymore.
More over, if you are tying your application into OrientDB asynchronous API, you do not have a proper Data Access Layer abstraction ?

Comment: You realize that the query will block in another thread, right? The query is still synchronous, wrapping or no.

Comment: The `Future` asynchronously executes on a different thread. Your argument that the query is synchronous when the blocking call is wrapped in a Future is totally bollocks.

Comment: Language, please. You admit yourself that the call/query is blocking. That is my point. It is blocking, even though it executes in a different thread. Blocking a thread is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I never admitted that the call/query is blocking when you wrap the call/query in a Future. It executes on a different thread, that's true. But you got the read handle to the data immediately after you made the call. So how is it blocking ? You have full control on the configuration of the threadpool (you can create a separate threadpool) on which the Futures execute.

Comment: The OrientDB query is blocking, so it must block the thread that calls it. Am I wrong in this? Anyway, I'm ready to end this argument. I don't see that we're getting anywhere.

Comment: Alright. Please take a look at other non-blocking DB drivers which are fully non-blocking and asynchronous (and implemented using Scala) like https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo, https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async. They use a similar approach as I have mentioned in my example.